# Cannot Delete Amazon ECS Cluster using CloudFormation

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I am using the following CloudFormation template to create ECS Cluster.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: 'AWS Cloudformation Template to create the Infrastructure'
Resources:
  ECSCluster:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
    Properties:
    ClusterName: 'Blog-iac-test-1'
  EC2InstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
    Path: /
    Roles: [!Ref 'EC2Role']
  ECSAutoScalingGroup:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
  Properties:
    VPCZoneIdentifier:
    - subnet-****
    LaunchConfigurationName: !Ref 'ECSAutoscalingLC'
    MinSize: '1'
    MaxSize: '2'
    DesiredCapacity: '1'
 ECSAutoscalingLC:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
    Properties:
      AssociatePublicIpAddress: true
      ImageId: 'ami-b743bed1'
      SecurityGroups:
      - sg-****
      InstanceType: 't2.micro'
      IamInstanceProfile: !Ref 'EC2InstanceProfile'
      KeyName: 'test'
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: !Sub |
        #!/bin/bash -xe
        echo ECS_CLUSTER=Blog-iac-test-1 >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
  EC2Role:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Statement:
      - Effect: Allow
      Principal:
        Service: [ec2.amazonaws.com]
        Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
      Path: /
  ECSServicePolicy:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Policy"
    Properties: 
      PolicyName: "root"
      PolicyDocument: 
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement: 
        - Effect: Allow
        Action: ['ecs:*', 'logs:*', 'ecr:*', 's3:*']
        Resource: '*'
    Roles: [!Ref 'EC2Role']
```

The stack is created successfully, but while destroying, I am getting the  following error:
**The Cluster cannot be deleted while Container Instances are active or draining.**

I was able to delete the stack earlier, this issue started to occur recently. 
What could be a workaround to avoid this issue ? Should I need to add some dependencies ?

Comment: When you were able to delete the stack earlier, did you have any tasks and services running on it? I don't see any ECS Services in your task definition, so if those are created out of scope, then you will likely need to scale down those services and tasks before trying to destroy the cluster.

Comment: @JamieStarke When I was able to delete the stack earlier, there were no tasks or services running on it. Even now, I don't have any tasks or services. I did scale them down before trying to destroy the cluster.

Comment: Hmmm, if they fully scaled to 0, and were draining, then I'd contact AWS Support, because that's a bug. That said, I'm betting that you scaled them down, but they didn't finish draining first.

Comment: ohk. For testing, I created a stack with the above template and tried deleting the stack before creating any services. The same issue persists. I think its a bug and should contact AWS support.

Comment: Can reproduce buy building my own ECS cluster that has no service or containers. Delete stack fails.

Comment: looks like this definitely should go to AWS support

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in [this AWS Documentation Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_CleaningUp.html), have you tried deregistering the instances as well?:

> **Deregister Container Instances:**
>   Before you can delete a cluster, you
>   must deregister the container instances inside that cluster. For each
>   container instance inside your cluster, follow the procedures in
>   Deregister a Container Instance to deregister it.
>
> Alternatively, you can use the following AWS CLI command to deregister
>   your container instances. Be sure to substitute the Region, cluster
>   name, and container instance ID for each container instance that you
>   are deregistering.
>
> `aws ecs deregister-container-instance --cluster default
>   --container-instance container_instance_id --region us-west-2 --force`